# Instead change the require of chai.js in to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, hardhat, testing

### .js file

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe("Token contract",function(){
it("Deployment should assign the total supply of the owner", async function(){
    const[owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log("Signers Object:",owner);
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");//instance contract

    const hardhatToken = await Token.deploy(); //deploy

    const ownerBalance = await hardhatToken.balanceOf(owner.address);//ownerBalance = 10000
    console.log("Owner Address:",owner.address);

    expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance)// total supply=10000

});
});
```

Package.json

```
  {
    "name": "testinghardhat",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
         "devDependencies": {
         "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
        "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
        "chai": "^5.0.3",
        "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.10",
        "ethers": "^5.7.2",
        "hardhat": "^2.19.4"
  },
       "dependencies": {
            "glob": "^7.2.0",
            "node-fetch": "^2.6.6"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using earlier "chai" version, for example, do `yarn add --dev chai@4.2.0` or `npm i --save-dev chai@4.2.0`, depending on your package manager. It worked well for me.